# How do you create a Distinct query in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, distinct

Is there a way to create a Distinct query in HQL.  Either by using the "distinct" keyword or some other method.  I am not sure if distinct is a valid keywork for HQL, but I am looking for the HQL equivalent of the SQL keyword "distinct".

Comment: Projection? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536868/criteria-distinct-root-entity-vs-projections-distinct

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Here's a snippet of hql that we use. (Names have been changed to protect identities)

```
String queryString = "select distinct f from Foo f inner join foo.bars as b" +
                " where f.creationDate >= ? and f.creationDate < ? and b.bar = ?";
        return getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString, new Object[] {startDate, endDate, bar});
```

Comment: I only ever used hibernate with MySQL - not sure how to deal with the mssql issue.

Comment: The function getHibernateTemplate() belongs to the Spring Framework, not to the standard API. Do you know of an equivalent without using the Spring Framework?

Comment: using the "distinct" keyword without the HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH hint set to 
 false may result in performance issues. 
We can use something like this: 
`query.setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false).getResultList()`
you can read more about this [here](https://in.relation.to/2016/08/04/introducing-distinct-pass-through-query-hint/)

Answer (score 62):

It's worth noting that the `distinct` keyword in HQL does not map directly to the `distinct` keyword in SQL.

If you use the `distinct` keyword in HQL, then sometimes Hibernate will use the `distinct` SQL keyword, but in some situations it will use a result transformer to produce distinct results. For example when you are using an outer join like this:

```
select distinct o from Order o left join fetch o.lineItems
```

It is not possible to filter out duplicates at the SQL level in this case, so Hibernate uses a `ResultTransformer` to filter duplicates **after** the SQL query has been performed.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471819/why-does-hibernate-hql-distinct-cause-an-sql-distinct-on-left-join/5495191#5495191

Answer (score 17):

do something like this next time

```
 Criteria crit = (Criteria) session.
                  createCriteria(SomeClass.class).
                  setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

 List claz = crit.list();
```

Comment: That's suboptimal: instead of discarding the repetitions at the database level, it will just pull the data from the database to the memory with repetitions and all, and then discard the repetitions afterwards; depending on how often the data repeats, that can increase the I/O operations quite a lot.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` with Hibernate HQL query as well.

Example:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from java_pojo_name");
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
return query.list();
```

Comment: That's suboptimal: instead of discarding the repetitions at the database level, it will just pull the data from the database to the memory with repetitions and all, and then discard the repetitions afterwards; depending on how often the data repeats, that can increase the I/O operations quite a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I had some problems with result transformers combined with HQL queries. When I tried

```
final ResultTransformer trans = new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer();
qry.setResultTransformer(trans);
```

it didn't work. I had to transform manually like this:

```
final List found = trans.transformList(qry.list());
```

With Criteria API transformers worked just fine.

Comment: to get to 10k (:

Answer (score 3):

My main query looked like this in the model:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getAllCentralFinancialAgencyAccountCd", 
    query = "select distinct i from CentralFinancialAgencyAccountCd i")
```

And I was still not getting what I considered "distinct" results.  They were just distinct based on a primary key combination on the table.

So in the `DaoImpl` I added an one line change and ended up getting the "distinct" return I wanted.  An example would be instead of seeing 00 four times I now just see it once.  Here is the code I added to the `DaoImpl`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<CacheModelBase> getAllCodes() {

    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    org.hibernate.Query q = session.getNamedQuery("getAllCentralFinancialAgencyAccountCd");
    q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); // This is the one line I had to add to make it do a more distinct query.
    List<CacheModelBase> codes;
    codes = q.list();
    return codes;       
}
```

I hope this helped!  Once again, this might only work if you are following coding practices that implement the service, dao, and model type of project.

Answer (score 3):

You can you the distinct keyword in you criteria builder like this.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Orders> query = builder.createQuery(Orders.class);
Root<Orders> root = query.from(Orders.class);
query.distinct(true).multiselect(root.get("cust_email").as(String.class));
```

And create the field constructor in your model class.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a Customer Entity mapped to CUSTOMER_INFORMATION table and you want to get list of distinct firstName of customer. You can use below snippet to get the same.

```
Query distinctFirstName = session.createQuery("select ci.firstName from Customer ci group by ci.firstName");
Object [] firstNamesRows = distinctFirstName.list();
```

I hope it helps. So here we are using group by instead of using distinct keyword.

Also previously I found it difficult to use distinct keyword when I want to apply it to multiple columns. For example I want of get list of distinct firstName, lastName then group by would simply work. I had difficulty in using distinct in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I have got a answer for Hibernate Query Language to use Distinct fields.
You can use *SELECT DISTINCT(TO_CITY) FROM FLIGHT_ROUTE*.
If you use *SQL* query, it return String List. You can't use it return value by Entity Class.
So the Answer to solve that type of Problem is use *HQL* with *SQL*.

```
FROM FLIGHT_ROUTE F WHERE F.ROUTE_ID IN (SELECT SF.ROUTE_ID FROM FLIGHT_ROUTE SF GROUP BY SF.TO_CITY);
```

From *SQL* query statement it got DISTINCT ROUTE_ID and input as a List.
And IN query filter the distinct TO_CITY from IN (List).

Return type is Entity Bean type.
So you can it in AJAX such as *AutoComplement*.

May all be OK

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use **new** keyword for a custom DTO in your select statement and need **distinct elements**, use new outside of new like as follows-

```
select distinct new com.org.AssetDTO(a.id, a.address, a.status) from Asset as a where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add GROUP BY instead of Distinct

```
@Query(value = "from someTableEntity where entityCode in :entityCode" +
            " group by entityCode, entityName, entityType")
List<someTableEntity > findNameByCode(@Param("entityCode") List<String> entityCode);
```