# How does DISTINCT work when using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, jpa, distinct

What column does DISTINCT work with in JPA and is it possible to change it?

Here's an example JPA query using DISTINCT:

```
select DISTINCT c from Customer c
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense - what column is the distinct based on? Is it specified on the Entity as an annotation because I couldn't find one?

I would like to specify the column to make the distinction on, something like:

```
select DISTINCT(c.name) c from Customer c
```

I'm using MySQL and Hibernate.

Comment: What specific role does @Id  play in the lifecycle of an entity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update: See the top-voted answer please.**

**My own is currently obsolete. Only kept here for historical reasons.**

---

Distinct in HQL is usually needed in Joins and not in simple examples like your own.

See also [How do you create a Distinct query in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263850/how-do-you-create-a-distinct-query-in-hql)

Comment: No offense, but how could this ever be accepted as an answer?

Comment: It was the only valid answer from 2009 until 2012

Answer (score 77):

You are close.

```
select DISTINCT(c.name) from Customer c
```

Comment: This only returns an array of that column though. How to return whole entities with this approach?

Comment: @cen - what you're asking for isn't logical.  If I have two customers (id=1234, name="Joe Customer") and (id=2345, name="Joe Customer"), which should be returned for such a query?  The results would be undefined.  Now, you could force it with something like (not sure quite how the syntax for this would work, but this should give the general idea): `select c from Customer c where id in (select min(d.id) from Customer d group by d.name)` ... but that's a situation dependent, because you need to come up with a way based on what attributes you have available to select one of the entities.

Comment: @Jules - in cases like this you usually don't really care which one is returned so any choosing technique is ok. I think mysql even handles this scenario by default. I don't remember the exact use case I had 2 years ago tho.

Comment: @Jules is there a way to map that returned object array with the enitity.

Answer (score 41):

Depending on the underlying JPQL or Criteria API query type, `DISTINCT` has two meanings in JPA.

### Scalar queries

For scalar queries, which return a scalar projection, like the following query:

```
List<Integer> publicationYears = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct year(p.createdOn)
    from Post p
    order by year(p.createdOn)
    """, Integer.class)
.getResultList();

LOGGER.info("Publication years: {}", publicationYears);
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword should be passed to the underlying SQL statement because we want the DB engine to filter duplicates prior to returning the result set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    extract(YEAR FROM p.created_on) AS col_0_0_
FROM
    post p
ORDER BY
    extract(YEAR FROM p.created_on)

-- Publication years: [2016, 2018]
```

### Hibernate 6

Hibernate 6 can deduplicate parent entity references automatically, so you don't need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword, as it were the case with Hibernate 5.

Therefore, when running the following query:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.title = :title
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter(
    "title", 
    "High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!"
)
.getResultList();

assertEquals(1, posts.size());
assertEquals(2, posts.get(0).getComments().size());
```

We can see that a single `Post` entity was fetched even if it has two associated `PostComment` child entities.

### Hibernate 5 entity queries

In JPA, for entity queries, `DISTINCT` has a different meaning.

Without using `DISTINCT`, a query like the following one:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.title = :title
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter(
    "title", 
    "High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!"
)
.getResultList();

LOGGER.info(
    "Fetched the following Post entity identifiers: {}", 
    posts.stream().map(Post::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

is going to JOIN the `post` and the `post_comment` tables like this:

```
SELECT p.id AS id1_0_0_,
       pc.id AS id1_1_1_,
       p.created_on AS created_2_0_0_,
       p.title AS title3_0_0_,
       pc.post_id AS post_id3_1_1_,
       pc.review AS review2_1_1_,
       pc.post_id AS post_id3_1_0__
FROM   post p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       post_comment pc ON p.id=pc.post_id
WHERE
       p.title='High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!'

-- Fetched the following Post entity identifiers: [1, 1]
```

But the parent `post` records are duplicated in the result set for each associated `post_comment` row. For this reason, the `List` of `Post` entities will contain duplicate `Post` entity references.

To eliminate the `Post` entity references, we need to use `DISTINCT`:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.title = :title
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter(
    "title", 
    "High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!"
)
.getResultList();
 
LOGGER.info(
    "Fetched the following Post entity identifiers: {}", 
    posts.stream().map(Post::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

But then `DISTINCT` is also passed to the SQL query, and that's not desirable at all:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       p.id AS id1_0_0_,
       pc.id AS id1_1_1_,
       p.created_on AS created_2_0_0_,
       p.title AS title3_0_0_,
       pc.post_id AS post_id3_1_1_,
       pc.review AS review2_1_1_,
       pc.post_id AS post_id3_1_0__
FROM   post p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       post_comment pc ON p.id=pc.post_id
WHERE
       p.title='High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!'
 
-- Fetched the following Post entity identifiers: [1]
```

By passing `DISTINCT` to the SQL query, the EXECUTION PLAN is going to execute an extra **Sort** phase which adds overhead without bringing any value since the parent-child combinations always return unique records because of the child PK column:

```
Unique  (cost=23.71..23.72 rows=1 width=1068) (actual time=0.131..0.132 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=23.71..23.71 rows=1 width=1068) (actual time=0.131..0.131 rows=2 loops=1)
        Sort Key: p.id, pc.id, p.created_on, pc.post_id, pc.review
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=11.76..23.70 rows=1 width=1068) (actual time=0.054..0.058 rows=2 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (pc.post_id = p.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on post_comment pc  (cost=0.00..11.40 rows=140 width=532) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=11.75..11.75 rows=1 width=528) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on post p  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=528) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((title)::text = 'High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 3
Planning time: 0.227 ms
Execution time: 0.179 ms
```

### Hibernate 5 entity queries with HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH

To eliminate the Sort phase from the execution plan, we need to use the [`HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpql-distinct-jpa-hibernate/) JPA query hint:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select distinct p
    from Post p
    left join fetch p.comments
    where p.title = :title
    """, Post.class)
.setParameter(
    "title", 
    "High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!"
)
.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
.getResultList();
 
LOGGER.info(
    "Fetched the following Post entity identifiers: {}", 
    posts.stream().map(Post::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

And now, the SQL query will not contain `DISTINCT` but `Post` entity reference duplicates are going to be removed:

```
SELECT
       p.id AS id1_0_0_,
       pc.id AS id1_1_1_,
       p.created_on AS created_2_0_0_,
       p.title AS title3_0_0_,
       pc.post_id AS post_id3_1_1_,
       pc.review AS review2_1_1_,
       pc.post_id AS post_id3_1_0__
FROM   post p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       post_comment pc ON p.id=pc.post_id
WHERE
       p.title='High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!'
 
-- Fetched the following Post entity identifiers: [1]
```

And the Execution Plan is going to confirm that we no longer have an extra Sort phase this time:

```
Hash Right Join  (cost=11.76..23.70 rows=1 width=1068) (actual time=0.066..0.069 rows=2 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (pc.post_id = p.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on post_comment pc  (cost=0.00..11.40 rows=140 width=532) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=11.75..11.75 rows=1 width=528) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        ->  Seq Scan on post p  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=528) (actual time=0.036..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
              Filter: ((title)::text = 'High-Performance Java Persistence eBook has been released!'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 3
Planning time: 1.184 ms
Execution time: 0.160 ms
```

> If you're using Hibernate 6, you no longer need the `QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH`, and you should remove it as it got removed from the framework.

Comment: Bought last week, not all the way through though ;-) Probably the best IT book I've  read

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer!! After reading the article you mentioned here and Spring Data JPA reference docs, achieved this on my Spring Data JPA Repository by adding this annotation on top of the method: `@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough", value = "false"))`

Comment: @dk7 This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: But the planning time have increased why is that so?

Comment: Thd time values are meaningless as thid is just test data.

Comment: @dk7 In my Spring Boot 1.5.9 application your advice did not work: "Ignoring unrecognized query hint [hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough]". Is there any hint key that I can use?

Comment: @İsmailYavuz The `PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` was implemented by [HHH-10965](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10965) and is available since Hibernate ORM 5.2.2. Spring Boot 1.5.9 is very old and uses Hibernate ORM 5.0.12. So, you need to upgrade your dependencies if you want to benefit from these awesome features.

Answer (score 13):

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.listUniqueNames", 
            query = "SELECT DISTINCT c.name FROM Customer c")
public class Customer {
        ...

        private String name;

        public static List<String> listUniqueNames() {
             return = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(
                   "Customer.listUniqueNames", String.class)
                   .getResultList();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I agree with *kazanaki*'s answer, and it helped me.
I wanted to select the whole entity, so I used

```
 select DISTINCT(c) from Customer c
```

In my case I have many-to-many relationship, and I want to load entities with collections in one query.

I used LEFT JOIN FETCH and at the end I had to make the result distinct.

Answer (score 5):

I would use JPA's constructor expression feature. See also following answer:

[JPQL Constructor Expression - org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:Table is not mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271305/jpql-constructor-expression-org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexceptiontable-i)

Following the example in the question, it would be something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT new com.mypackage.MyNameType(c.name) from Customer c
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer who is slightly specific, in case someone encounters the same issue as I did and finds this question.

I used JPQL with query annotations (no query building).
And I needed to get distinct values for an Entity that was *embedded* into another entity, the relationship was asserted via a Many To One annotation.

I have two database tables :

- **MainEntity**, which I want with distinct values
- **LinkEntity**, which is a relationship table between MainEntity and another table. It has a composite primary key formed with its three columns.

In Java Spring code, this leads to three classes implemented :

**LinkEntity :**

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="link_entity")
public class LinkEntity implements Entity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private LinkEntityPK pk;

    // ... Getter, setter, toString()
}
```

**LinkEntityPK :**

```
@Embeddable
public class LinkEntityPK implements Entity, Serializable {

    /** The main entity we want to have distinct values of */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "code_entity")
    private MainEntity mainEntity;

    /** */
    @Column(name = "code_pk2")
    private String codeOperation;

    /** */
    @Column(name = "code_pk3")
    private String codeFonction;
```

**MainEntity :**

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "main_entity")
public class MainEntity implements Entity {

    /** We use this for LinkEntity*/
    @Id
    @Column(name="code_entity")
    private String codeEntity;


    private String name;
    // And other attributes, getters and setters
```

So the final query to get distinct values for the main entity is :

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<LinkEntity, String> {

    @Query(
        "Select " +
            "Distinct linkEntity.pk.intervenant " +
        "From " +
            "LinkEntity as linkEntity " +
            "Join MainEntity as mainEntity On " +
                 "mainEntity = linkEntity.pk.mainEntity ")
    List<MainEntity> getMainEntityList();

}
```

Hope this can help someone.