# Is it possibele to write this SQL statement using HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

There is sql statement

```
select distinct create_date from articles
```

Is it possibele to write this statement using HQL?

Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263850/how-do-you-create-a-distinct-query-in-hql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. HQL supports the `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.createDate FROM Article a
```

I'd propose naming your entity `Article` (rather than `articles`) and to use camelCase (rather than under_score)