# why does hibernate hql distinct cause an sql distinct on left join?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, distinct

I've got this test HQL:

```
select distinct o from Order o left join fetch o.lineItems
```

and it *does* generate an SQL distinct without an obvious reason:

```
select distinct order0_.id as id61_0_, orderline1_.order_id as order1_62_1_...
```

The SQL resultset is always the same (with and without an SQL distinct):

```
order id | order name | orderline id | orderline name
---------+------------+--------------+---------------
       1 | foo        |            1 | foo item
       1 | foo        |            2 | bar item
       1 | foo        |            3 | test item
       2 | empty      |         NULL | NULL
       3 | bar        |            4 | qwerty item
       3 | bar        |            5 | asdfgh item
```

Why does hibernate generate the SQL distinct? The SQL distinct doesn't make any sense and makes the query slower than needed.
This is contrary to the [FAQ](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword) which mentions that hql distinct in this case is just a shortcut for the result transformer:

> session.createQuery("select distinct o
>   from Order o left join fetch
>   o.lineItems").list();
>
> It looks like you are using the SQL DISTINCT keyword here. Of course, this is not SQL, this is HQL. This distinct is just a shortcut for the result transformer, in this case. Yes, in other cases an HQL distinct will translate straight into a SQL DISTINCT. Not in this case: you can not filter out duplicates at the SQL level, the very nature of a product/join forbids this - you want the duplicates or you don't get all the data you need.

thanks

Comment: How lineitems are mapped, as List or Set? First allows duplicates and distinct makes sense, the latter is not.

Comment: I've encountered this issue as well. And Postgres doesn't seem to optimize away this redundant distinct, so this distinct will definitely affect execution plan for Postgres database. I believe this is bug with Hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

Have a closer look at the sql statement that hibernate generates - yes it does use the "distinct" keyword but not in the way I think you are expecting it to (or the way that the Hibernate FAQ is implying) i.e. to return a set of "distinct" or "unique" orders.

It doesn't use the distinct keyword to return distinct orders, as that wouldn't make sense in that SQL query, considering the join that you have also specified.

The resulting sql set still needs processing by the ResultTransformer, as clearly the sql set contains duplicate orders. That's why they say that the HQL distinct keyword doesn't directly map to the SQL distinct keyword.

Comment: It does generate an SQL distinct (together with a ResultTransformer). The SQL distinct doesn't make any sense and makes the query slower than needed.

Comment: That's probably a separate issue then. You might be expecting too much if you think that every generated sql query should be optimal, that's not really Hibernate's purpose.

Comment: Please read the question again. This is my only and exact problem. It contrasts what the documentation says. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is about the specifics of the hibernate implementation of this feature - and your problem is that the query is slower than it could be. I don't know why the implementation is this way. However the comment in the FAQ was made in the context of explaining why the HQL keyword does not always directly map to the SQL keyword. It was not made in the context of explaining the specifics of what will happen with every generated SQL query. So I can't answer your question, but I think I can explain the perceived inconsistency you are seeing in the FAQ. I guess that's not really an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and I think this is an Hibernate issue (not a bug because code doesn't fail). However, I have to dig deeper to make sure it's an issue.

Hibernate (at least in version 4 which its the version I'm working on my project, specifically 4.3.11) uses the concept of SPI, long story short: its like an API to extend or modify the framework.

I took advantage of this feature to replace the classes `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory` (This class is called by Hibernate and delegates the job of generating the SQL query) and `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl` (This is sort of an internal class which is called by `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory` and generates the actual SQL query). I did it as follows:

Replacement for `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory`:

```
package org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast;

import java.util.Map;
import org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.EntityGraphQueryHint;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.hql.spi.QueryTranslator;

public class NoDistinctInSQLASTQueryTranslatorFactory extends ASTQueryTranslatorFactory {

    @Override
    public QueryTranslator createQueryTranslator(String queryIdentifier, String queryString, Map filters, SessionFactoryImplementor factory, EntityGraphQueryHint entityGraphQueryHint) {
        return new NoDistinctInSQLQueryTranslatorImpl(queryIdentifier, queryString, filters, factory, entityGraphQueryHint);
    }

}
```

Replacement for `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl`:

```
package org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.QueryException;
import org.hibernate.ScrollableResults;
import org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.EntityGraphQueryHint;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.RowSelection;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventSource;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlTokenTypes;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlTokenTypes;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlTokenTypes;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.MultiTableDeleteExecutor;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.MultiTableUpdateExecutor;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.StatementExecutor;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregatedSelectExpression;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.InsertStatement;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.QueryNode;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.Statement;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTUtil;
import org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser;
import org.hibernate.hql.spi.FilterTranslator;
import org.hibernate.hql.spi.ParameterTranslations;
import org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.StringHelper;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.IdentitySet;
import org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader;
import org.hibernate.param.ParameterSpecification;
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.Queryable;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import antlr.ANTLRException;
import antlr.RecognitionException;
import antlr.TokenStreamException;
import antlr.collections.AST;

/**
 * A QueryTranslator that uses an Antlr-based parser.
 *
 * @author Joshua Davis (pgmjsd@sourceforge.net)
 */
public class NoDistinctInSQLQueryTranslatorImpl extends QueryTranslatorImpl implements FilterTranslator {

    private static final CoreMessageLogger LOG = Logger.getMessageLogger(
            CoreMessageLogger.class,
            QueryTranslatorImpl.class.getName()
    );

    private SessionFactoryImplementor factory;

    private final String queryIdentifier;
    private String hql;
    private boolean shallowQuery;
    private Map tokenReplacements;

    //TODO:this is only needed during compilation .. can we eliminate the instvar?
    private Map enabledFilters;

    private boolean compiled;
    private QueryLoader queryLoader;
    private StatementExecutor statementExecutor;

    private Statement sqlAst;
    private String sql;

    private ParameterTranslations paramTranslations;
    private List<ParameterSpecification> collectedParameterSpecifications;

    private EntityGraphQueryHint entityGraphQueryHint;

    /**
     * Creates a new AST-based query translator.
     *
     * @param queryIdentifier The query-identifier (used in stats collection)
     * @param query The hql query to translate
     * @param enabledFilters Currently enabled filters
     * @param factory The session factory constructing this translator instance.
     */
    public NoDistinctInSQLQueryTranslatorImpl(
            String queryIdentifier,
            String query,
            Map enabledFilters,
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
        super(queryIdentifier, query, enabledFilters, factory);
        this.queryIdentifier = queryIdentifier;
        this.hql = query;
        this.compiled = false;
        this.shallowQuery = false;
        this.enabledFilters = enabledFilters;
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public NoDistinctInSQLQueryTranslatorImpl(
            String queryIdentifier,
            String query,
            Map enabledFilters,
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory,
            EntityGraphQueryHint entityGraphQueryHint) {
        this(queryIdentifier, query, enabledFilters, factory);
        this.entityGraphQueryHint = entityGraphQueryHint;
    }

    /**
     * Compile a "normal" query. This method may be called multiple times.
     * Subsequent invocations are no-ops.
     *
     * @param replacements Defined query substitutions.
     * @param shallow Does this represent a shallow (scalar or entity-id)
     * select?
     * @throws QueryException There was a problem parsing the query string.
     * @throws MappingException There was a problem querying defined mappings.
     */
    @Override
    public void compile(
            Map replacements,
            boolean shallow) throws QueryException, MappingException {
        doCompile(replacements, shallow, null);
    }

    /**
     * Compile a filter. This method may be called multiple times. Subsequent
     * invocations are no-ops.
     *
     * @param collectionRole the role name of the collection used as the basis
     * for the filter.
     * @param replacements Defined query substitutions.
     * @param shallow Does this represent a shallow (scalar or entity-id)
     * select?
     * @throws QueryException There was a problem parsing the query string.
     * @throws MappingException There was a problem querying defined mappings.
     */
    @Override
    public void compile(
            String collectionRole,
            Map replacements,
            boolean shallow) throws QueryException, MappingException {
        doCompile(replacements, shallow, collectionRole);
    }

    /**
     * Performs both filter and non-filter compiling.
     *
     * @param replacements Defined query substitutions.
     * @param shallow Does this represent a shallow (scalar or entity-id)
     * select?
     * @param collectionRole the role name of the collection used as the basis
     * for the filter, NULL if this is not a filter.
     */
    private synchronized void doCompile(Map replacements, boolean shallow, String collectionRole) {
        // If the query is already compiled, skip the compilation.
        if (compiled) {
            LOG.debug("compile() : The query is already compiled, skipping...");
            return;
        }

        // Remember the parameters for the compilation.
        this.tokenReplacements = replacements;
        if (tokenReplacements == null) {
            tokenReplacements = new HashMap();
        }
        this.shallowQuery = shallow;

        try {
            // PHASE 1 : Parse the HQL into an AST.
            final HqlParser parser = parse(true);

            // PHASE 2 : Analyze the HQL AST, and produce an SQL AST.
            final HqlSqlWalker w = analyze(parser, collectionRole);

            sqlAst = (Statement) w.getAST();

            // at some point the generate phase needs to be moved out of here,
            // because a single object-level DML might spawn multiple SQL DML
            // command executions.
            //
            // Possible to just move the sql generation for dml stuff, but for
            // consistency-sake probably best to just move responsiblity for
            // the generation phase completely into the delegates
            // (QueryLoader/StatementExecutor) themselves.  Also, not sure why
            // QueryLoader currently even has a dependency on this at all; does
            // it need it?  Ideally like to see the walker itself given to the delegates directly...
            if (sqlAst.needsExecutor()) {
                statementExecutor = buildAppropriateStatementExecutor(w);
            } else {
                // PHASE 3 : Generate the SQL.
                generate((QueryNode) sqlAst);
                queryLoader = new QueryLoader(this, factory, w.getSelectClause());
            }

            compiled = true;
        } catch (QueryException qe) {
            if (qe.getQueryString() == null) {
                throw qe.wrapWithQueryString(hql);
            } else {
                throw qe;
            }
        } catch (RecognitionException e) {
            // we do not actually propagate ANTLRExceptions as a cause, so
            // log it here for diagnostic purposes
            LOG.trace("Converted antlr.RecognitionException", e);
            throw QuerySyntaxException.convert(e, hql);
        } catch (ANTLRException e) {
            // we do not actually propagate ANTLRExceptions as a cause, so
            // log it here for diagnostic purposes
            LOG.trace("Converted antlr.ANTLRException", e);
            throw new QueryException(e.getMessage(), hql);
        }

        //only needed during compilation phase...
        this.enabledFilters = null;
    }

    private void generate(AST sqlAst) throws QueryException, RecognitionException {
        if (sql == null) {
            final SqlGenerator gen = new SqlGenerator(factory);
            gen.statement(sqlAst);
            sql = gen.getSQL();
            //Hack: The distinct operator is removed from the sql 
            //string to avoid executing a distinct query in the db server when 
            //the distinct is used in hql.
            sql = sql.replace("distinct", "");
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debugf("HQL: %s", hql);
                LOG.debugf("SQL: %s", sql);
            }
            gen.getParseErrorHandler().throwQueryException();
            collectedParameterSpecifications = gen.getCollectedParameters();
        }
    }

    private static final ASTPrinter SQL_TOKEN_PRINTER = new ASTPrinter(SqlTokenTypes.class);

    private HqlSqlWalker analyze(HqlParser parser, String collectionRole) throws QueryException, RecognitionException {
        final HqlSqlWalker w = new HqlSqlWalker(this, factory, parser, tokenReplacements, collectionRole);
        final AST hqlAst = parser.getAST();

        // Transform the tree.
        w.statement(hqlAst);

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug(SQL_TOKEN_PRINTER.showAsString(w.getAST(), "--- SQL AST ---"));
        }

        w.getParseErrorHandler().throwQueryException();

        return w;
    }

    private HqlParser parse(boolean filter) throws TokenStreamException, RecognitionException {
        // Parse the query string into an HQL AST.
        final HqlParser parser = HqlParser.getInstance(hql);
        parser.setFilter(filter);

        LOG.debugf("parse() - HQL: %s", hql);
        parser.statement();

        final AST hqlAst = parser.getAST();

        final NodeTraverser walker = new NodeTraverser(new JavaConstantConverter());
        walker.traverseDepthFirst(hqlAst);

        showHqlAst(hqlAst);

        parser.getParseErrorHandler().throwQueryException();
        return parser;
    }

    private static final ASTPrinter HQL_TOKEN_PRINTER = new ASTPrinter(HqlTokenTypes.class);

    @Override
    void showHqlAst(AST hqlAst) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug(HQL_TOKEN_PRINTER.showAsString(hqlAst, "--- HQL AST ---"));
        }
    }

    private void errorIfDML() throws HibernateException {
        if (sqlAst.needsExecutor()) {
            throw new QueryExecutionRequestException("Not supported for DML operations", hql);
        }
    }

    private void errorIfSelect() throws HibernateException {
        if (!sqlAst.needsExecutor()) {
            throw new QueryExecutionRequestException("Not supported for select queries", hql);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getQueryIdentifier() {
        return queryIdentifier;
    }

    @Override
    public Statement getSqlAST() {
        return sqlAst;
    }

    private HqlSqlWalker getWalker() {
        return sqlAst.getWalker();
    }

    /**
     * Types of the return values of an <tt>iterate()</tt> style query.
     *
     * @return an array of <tt>Type</tt>s.
     */
    @Override
    public Type[] getReturnTypes() {
        errorIfDML();
        return getWalker().getReturnTypes();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getReturnAliases() {
        errorIfDML();
        return getWalker().getReturnAliases();
    }

    @Override
    public String[][] getColumnNames() {
        errorIfDML();
        return getWalker().getSelectClause().getColumnNames();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Serializable> getQuerySpaces() {
        return getWalker().getQuerySpaces();
    }

    @Override
    public List list(SessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
            throws HibernateException {
        // Delegate to the QueryLoader...
        errorIfDML();

        final QueryNode query = (QueryNode) sqlAst;
        final boolean hasLimit = queryParameters.getRowSelection() != null && queryParameters.getRowSelection().definesLimits();
        final boolean needsDistincting = (query.getSelectClause().isDistinct() || hasLimit) && containsCollectionFetches();

        QueryParameters queryParametersToUse;
        if (hasLimit && containsCollectionFetches()) {
            LOG.firstOrMaxResultsSpecifiedWithCollectionFetch();
            RowSelection selection = new RowSelection();
            selection.setFetchSize(queryParameters.getRowSelection().getFetchSize());
            selection.setTimeout(queryParameters.getRowSelection().getTimeout());
            queryParametersToUse = queryParameters.createCopyUsing(selection);
        } else {
            queryParametersToUse = queryParameters;
        }

        List results = queryLoader.list(session, queryParametersToUse);

        if (needsDistincting) {
            int includedCount = -1;
            // NOTE : firstRow is zero-based
            int first = !hasLimit || queryParameters.getRowSelection().getFirstRow() == null
                    ? 0
                    : queryParameters.getRowSelection().getFirstRow();
            int max = !hasLimit || queryParameters.getRowSelection().getMaxRows() == null
                    ? -1
                    : queryParameters.getRowSelection().getMaxRows();
            List tmp = new ArrayList();
            IdentitySet distinction = new IdentitySet();
            for (final Object result : results) {
                if (!distinction.add(result)) {
                    continue;
                }
                includedCount++;
                if (includedCount < first) {
                    continue;
                }
                tmp.add(result);
                // NOTE : ( max - 1 ) because first is zero-based while max is not...
                if (max >= 0 && (includedCount - first) >= (max - 1)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            results = tmp;
        }

        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Return the query results as an iterator
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator iterate(QueryParameters queryParameters, EventSource session)
            throws HibernateException {
        // Delegate to the QueryLoader...
        errorIfDML();
        return queryLoader.iterate(queryParameters, session);
    }

    /**
     * Return the query results, as an instance of <tt>ScrollableResults</tt>
     */
    @Override
    public ScrollableResults scroll(QueryParameters queryParameters, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException {
        // Delegate to the QueryLoader...
        errorIfDML();
        return queryLoader.scroll(queryParameters, session);
    }

    @Override
    public int executeUpdate(QueryParameters queryParameters, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException {
        errorIfSelect();
        return statementExecutor.execute(queryParameters, session);
    }

    /**
     * The SQL query string to be called; implemented by all subclasses
     */
    @Override
    public String getSQLString() {
        return sql;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> collectSqlStrings() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (isManipulationStatement()) {
            String[] sqlStatements = statementExecutor.getSqlStatements();
            Collections.addAll(list, sqlStatements);
        } else {
            list.add(sql);
        }
        return list;
    }

    // -- Package local methods for the QueryLoader delegate --
    @Override
    public boolean isShallowQuery() {
        return shallowQuery;
    }

    @Override
    public String getQueryString() {
        return hql;
    }

    @Override
    public Map getEnabledFilters() {
        return enabledFilters;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getNamedParameterLocs(String name) {
        return getWalker().getNamedParameterLocations(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsCollectionFetches() {
        errorIfDML();
        List collectionFetches = ((QueryNode) sqlAst).getFromClause().getCollectionFetches();
        return collectionFetches != null && collectionFetches.size() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isManipulationStatement() {
        return sqlAst.needsExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public void validateScrollability() throws HibernateException {
        // Impl Note: allows multiple collection fetches as long as the
        // entire fecthed graph still "points back" to a single
        // root entity for return

        errorIfDML();

        final QueryNode query = (QueryNode) sqlAst;

        // If there are no collection fetches, then no further checks are needed
        List collectionFetches = query.getFromClause().getCollectionFetches();
        if (collectionFetches.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        // A shallow query is ok (although technically there should be no fetching here...)
        if (isShallowQuery()) {
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise, we have a non-scalar select with defined collection fetch(es).
        // Make sure that there is only a single root entity in the return (no tuples)
        if (getReturnTypes().length > 1) {
            throw new HibernateException("cannot scroll with collection fetches and returned tuples");
        }

        FromElement owner = null;
        for (Object o : query.getSelectClause().getFromElementsForLoad()) {
            // should be the first, but just to be safe...
            final FromElement fromElement = (FromElement) o;
            if (fromElement.getOrigin() == null) {
                owner = fromElement;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (owner == null) {
            throw new HibernateException("unable to locate collection fetch(es) owner for scrollability checks");
        }

        // This is not strictly true.  We actually just need to make sure that
        // it is ordered by root-entity PK and that that order-by comes before
        // any non-root-entity ordering...
        AST primaryOrdering = query.getOrderByClause().getFirstChild();
        if (primaryOrdering != null) {
            // TODO : this is a bit dodgy, come up with a better way to check this (plus see above comment)
            String[] idColNames = owner.getQueryable().getIdentifierColumnNames();
            String expectedPrimaryOrderSeq = StringHelper.join(
                    ", ",
                    StringHelper.qualify(owner.getTableAlias(), idColNames)
            );
            if (!primaryOrdering.getText().startsWith(expectedPrimaryOrderSeq)) {
                throw new HibernateException("cannot scroll results with collection fetches which are not ordered primarily by the root entity's PK");
            }
        }
    }

    private StatementExecutor buildAppropriateStatementExecutor(HqlSqlWalker walker) {
        final Statement statement = (Statement) walker.getAST();
        switch (walker.getStatementType()) {
            case HqlSqlTokenTypes.DELETE: {
                final FromElement fromElement = walker.getFinalFromClause().getFromElement();
                final Queryable persister = fromElement.getQueryable();
                if (persister.isMultiTable()) {
                    return new MultiTableDeleteExecutor(walker);
                } else {
                    return new DeleteExecutor(walker, persister);
                }
            }
            case HqlSqlTokenTypes.UPDATE: {
                final FromElement fromElement = walker.getFinalFromClause().getFromElement();
                final Queryable persister = fromElement.getQueryable();
                if (persister.isMultiTable()) {
                    // even here, if only properties mapped to the "base table" are referenced
                    // in the set and where clauses, this could be handled by the BasicDelegate.
                    // TODO : decide if it is better performance-wise to doAfterTransactionCompletion that check, or to simply use the MultiTableUpdateDelegate
                    return new MultiTableUpdateExecutor(walker);
                } else {
                    return new BasicExecutor(walker, persister);
                }
            }
            case HqlSqlTokenTypes.INSERT:
                return new BasicExecutor(walker, ((InsertStatement) statement).getIntoClause().getQueryable());
            default:
                throw new QueryException("Unexpected statement type");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ParameterTranslations getParameterTranslations() {
        if (paramTranslations == null) {
            paramTranslations = new ParameterTranslationsImpl(getWalker().getParameters());
        }
        return paramTranslations;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ParameterSpecification> getCollectedParameterSpecifications() {
        return collectedParameterSpecifications;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getDynamicInstantiationResultType() {
        AggregatedSelectExpression aggregation = queryLoader.getAggregatedSelectExpression();
        return aggregation == null ? null : aggregation.getAggregationResultType();
    }

    public static class JavaConstantConverter implements NodeTraverser.VisitationStrategy {

        private AST dotRoot;

        @Override
        public void visit(AST node) {
            if (dotRoot != null) {
                // we are already processing a dot-structure
                if (ASTUtil.isSubtreeChild(dotRoot, node)) {
                    return;
                }
                // we are now at a new tree level
                dotRoot = null;
            }

            if (node.getType() == HqlTokenTypes.DOT) {
                dotRoot = node;
                handleDotStructure(dotRoot);
            }
        }

        private void handleDotStructure(AST dotStructureRoot) {
            final String expression = ASTUtil.getPathText(dotStructureRoot);
            final Object constant = ReflectHelper.getConstantValue(expression);
            if (constant != null) {
                dotStructureRoot.setFirstChild(null);
                dotStructureRoot.setType(HqlTokenTypes.JAVA_CONSTANT);
                dotStructureRoot.setText(expression);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public EntityGraphQueryHint getEntityGraphQueryHint() {
        return entityGraphQueryHint;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEntityGraphQueryHint(EntityGraphQueryHint entityGraphQueryHint) {
        this.entityGraphQueryHint = entityGraphQueryHint;
    }
}
```

If you follow the code flow you will notice that I just modified the method `private void generate(AST sqlAst) throws QueryException, RecognitionException` and added the a following lines:

```
//Hack: The distinct keywordis removed from the sql string to 
//avoid executing a distinct query in the DBMS when the distinct 
//is used in hql.
sql = sql.replace("distinct", "");
```

What I do with this code is to remove the distinct keyword from the generated SQL query.

After creating the classes above, I added the following line in the hibernate configuration file:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.NoDistinctInSQLASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

This line tells hibernate to use my custom class to parse HQL queries and generate SQL queries without the distinct keyword. Notice I created my custom classes in the same package where the original HQL parser resides.