# How to get unique results from joined Hibernate queries

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, distinct

This is a continuation to questions like this:
[why does hibernate hql distinct cause an sql distinct on left join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471819/why-does-hibernate-hql-distinct-cause-an-sql-distinct-on-left-join)

You may have noticed that `findAll()` repository methods return duplicates, while `findAll(Pageble pageble)` works fine.

So, I would like to share additional way to obtain unique results.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's have a look at `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl`

```
final boolean hasLimit = queryParameters.getRowSelection() != null && queryParameters.getRowSelection().definesLimits();
final boolean needsDistincting = ( query.getSelectClause().isDistinct() || hasLimit ) && containsCollectionFetches();
```

As you can see, Hibernate will apply distincting if you define limits. That is, if you are afraid of the word `distinct` in your queries and criteria, just call `javax.persistence.Query.setFirstResult(0);` and this will make Hibernate apply distincting.