# Hibernate distinct clause problem

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, distinct

I searched a lot around but cannot find the answer:

I have the following SQL query:

```
select distinct l.id_book from wa2011.tb_lending as l where l.id_user = 1
```

It's a very simple query but I cannot manage to write it. How can I write this in HQL?

Thanks a lot!
Cheers.

Comment: Looks like a duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263850/how-do-you-create-a-distinct-query-in-hql

Comment: I had seen that post earlier but I couldn't realize if the "...inner join foo.bars ..." foo.bars part is an object or what...

Comment: You got the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code with Hibernate 3.3.2 and MS SQL Server and it works fine:

```
select distinct u.id from User u where u.login='admin'
```

So I think your HQL code should looks almost the same (just rewrite it from SQL to object model mapped to Hibernate).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the field I want to be unique is actually another object. If I put the clause "distinct x.bookBean bla bla bla" the result will be a list of BookBean object and not of the object on the "from" clause.

Comment: Tested with many-to-one mapping and also everything works fine. Which exception did you get?