# Select distinct with Spring Hibernate Sessionfactory

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring, sessionfactory

this would be my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM city;
```

this is my code at the moment:

```
public List<City> listCities() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from City").list();
}
```

which means:

```
SELECT * FROM city;
```

How must I change the code, so the query would be correct?

I hope I gave enough information, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263850/how-do-you-create-a-distinct-query-in-hql

Comment: @erac : it is not using spring there nor sessionfactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write the following HQL:
`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct from City").list()`
or even better (with result transformer):

```
Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from City");
q.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Comment: seems reasonable, but don't I have to also include the name of the field I wanna query as `DISTINCT` ? like this `SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s)
FROM table_name`

Comment: What would the return type would be when going with second solution?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT doesn't follow SQL guidelines but HQL one - meaning, distinction is done by id. Return type for the 2nd solution is your City entity. i find the 2nd one better in most cases.