# Use SELECT DISTINCT in createQuery returning a list value

Tags: java, hql, dao

I can't add `SELECT DISTINCT taxtCode` from this code:

```
public List<TblTaxType> findAlltaxtCode(String bfnsCode) {
        List<TblTaxType> result = null;

        String hql = "select distinct(taxtCode) from TblTaxType tbl_tax_type WHERE bfnsCode = ?";
        try {

                setSession(HibernateUtil.getSession());

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List <TblTaxType>  resultList = getSession().createQuery(hql)
                                                            .setString(0, bfnsCode)
                                                            .list();


            if(!resultList.isEmpty()){  
                result = resultList; 
                Debugger.print("TAX CODES FOUND ");
            }else{
                Debugger.print("TAX CODES NOT FOUND ");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Debugger.print(" TAX CODES NOT FOUND ");

        }

        Debugger.print(hql);
        closeSession();
        return result;
    }
```

Updated into whole code. The query is right but it seems its not returning a list value. Still `java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.test.test.TblTaxType` error appearing. How this query returns a list of value? The error occurs whenever a word DISTINCT is added. Is it impossible in HQL to use a distinct and return a list of value like in SQL Query?

Comment: can u write a bit more about your table structure??

Comment: I want to distinct the column name taxtCode whenever it finds the bfnsCode from table TblTaxType. The only problem here is I can't add a select tag, just started from `FROM` then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using `GROUP BY` instead by using `DISTINCT`.

```
String hql = "FROM TblTaxType tbl_tax_type WHERE bfnsCode = ? GROUP BY taxtCode";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Criteria and Projection together :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property( "id" )));
```

Hope it help someone.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your query with `FROM TblTaxType` OR `Select *` it returns the table rows with all your table Columns and assigns it to the list with `List <TblTaxType> DataType` hence it doesn't give any error.

But when you write `Select colName` it returns only the string present in that table cell. Which it can't convert to `java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.test.test.classes.TblTaxType`

There is no Problem in Using Distinct in Hibernate. See here :- [How do you create a Distinct query in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263850/how-do-you-create-a-distinct-query-in-hql)

Comment: So what should I do to return a string list value with distinct?

Answer (score 0):

the right wat to do this with hibernate is

```
select tbl_tax_type  FROM TblTaxType tbl_tax_type WHERE BFNS_CODE = ?
```

**EDIT 2**

to get specific list of distinct column use:

```
select distinct(taxtCode) from TblTaxType WHERE BFNS_CODE = ?
```

and in hibernate you don't have to use the first select statement to get a list, just use the from statement like this:

```
from TblTaxType where BFNS_CODE = ?
```

Comment: Still `java.lang.String cannot be cast`. I think its not returning a string list.

Comment: `ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - line 1:40: unexpected token: tbl_tax_type`

Comment: Edit it to `select distinct(tbl_tax_type.taxtCode) FROM TblTaxType tbl_tax_type WHERE bfnsCode = ?` Still **java.lang.String cannot be cast**

Comment: please try my new edit, and I tried a similar query in my application and it works perfectly, you made me suspect myself. check your coding, but this is the right way to it hibernate

Comment: Sorry but its not really working. I post my answer. Solving using that code. Kindly check it.

Comment: what database you're using ?