# Postgresql 'select distinct on' in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

Does hibernate has support on select distinct on queries?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (location) location, time, report
FROM weather_reports
ORDER BY location, time DESC;
```

Is there a way to create hibernate criterias for that query?

Comment: Since it's a PostgreSQL-specific feature, I suspect the answer will be "No".

Comment: No, I guess you'll have to use native sql

Comment: If you cannot use native queries, you can create a view and map it to a Hibernate entity just like a normal table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there was all "suspecting" and "guessing" here, when I stumbled across this question, I'll answer it definitely:

No, Hibernate does not support a DISTINCT ON query.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 17
[SELECT DISTINCT ON (location) location, time, report FROM weather_reports ORDER BY location, time DESC]
```

Tested under Hibernate 4.3.9-final

Please note that this doesn't apply to normal DISTINCT queries.
See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263850...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263850/how-do-you-create-a-distinct-query-in-hql)