# Postgres DISTINCT ON eqivalent in Hibernate Query Language

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hql

I need **Postgres** `DISTINCT ON` equivalent in HQL. For example consider the following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Col2) Col1, Col4 FROM tablename;
```

on table

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
---------------------------------
AA1  | A    |  2    | 1
AA2  | A    |  4    | 2
BB1  | B    |  2    | 3
BB2  | B    |  5    | 4
```

`Col2` will not be shown in the result as below

```
Col1 | Col4
------------
AA1  |  1
BB1  |  3
```

Can anyone give a solution in HQL. I need to use `DISTINCT` as it is part of a bigger query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but I misread your question:

**No, Hibernate does not support a DISTINCT ON query.**

Here is possible duplicate of your question: [Postgresql 'select distinct on' in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320185/postgresql-select-distinct-on-in-hibernate)

Comment: What is the SQL generated for that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I can't use Criteria for some reasons. I need query (HQL).