# HSQL. How to exclude duplicate elements using Distinct

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have duplicate in result in hibernate query, such as:

```
select new ValueObject(h.id, c.firstName, c.lastName) 
from HistoryTable as h left join CustomerTable as c
where h.customerId = c.id and c.notDeleted
order by c.firstName, c.lastName
```

But, when i used DISTINCT, duplicate in result continue to appear

```
select distinct new ValueObject(h.id, c.firstName, c.lastName) 
from HistoryTable as h left join CustomerTable as c
where h.customerId = c.id and c.notDeleted
order by c.firstName, c.lastName
```

But my question is, if there is any possibility to using DISTINCT for excluding duplicates for creating new ValueObject in HSQLDB query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not return distinct results for a query with left or right join.
You can use Hiberante `setResultTransformer` for your purposes. For more detail's explanations, why and how it resolve, look:

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword

and

[How do you create a Distinct query in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263850/how-do-you-create-a-distinct-query-in-hql)

Comment: Thank you for thing with setResultTransformer. I have not knew this function. But really distinct is work with left outer join, and i have found cause of the fault immediately after placement of the post.